# Is there any datatype that can store data more than 2 gb in sql server

Tags: sql, database, functional-programming

I am having requirement to store more than 2 gigabytes data in a column. Is there any way that I can do it? I need the data what I store need to be in database not in computer which results when using file stream concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO** there isn't. `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is the datatype which can be used to store 2GB of data in a column. But you can not store more than 2GB of data in it so that the upper limit to the datatype.

On a side note what makes you store such a big data in a column as this may cause you a lot of performance overhead and also it might not be a worthy thing to proceed with. I am sure you may find alternatives to that.

Possible alternatives may be to split the data and store it into multiple rows.
Else as commented by Mladen Prajdic you can use **[Filestream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx)** to store more than 2Gb of data.

Comment: Yes. I know that. But I am having requirement where I need to store more than 2gb. for example if i want to store 3gb data then what i have to do?

Comment: @GiriPrasad:- I would suggest you to split it and store that into two rows.

Comment: Use FileStream or FileTables https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx

Comment: @GiriPrasad:- I am not sure but hope you are aware that 2 GB of data is approximately 1 billion characters. I would highly recommend to split your data else you may face performance issue. :)